# Shadow angle calculation for solar tracking application

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[Shadow Length](http://www.mysolarpannels.com/optimum-angle-for-solar-panels/)

Dear all,

**I am looking for relationship Between Lmin and solar radiation angle.I know Here in above link they provided relation. But i don't know how to calculate it.
x- modules length=1200mm
ω-modules angle is changes with time of day.**Here MY module angle will be 45 till 7AM-9:30 AM. This angle need to change because of shadow . So how to calculate new shadow angle.

MY module angle will be -45 till 3:30pm-6pm. This angle need to change because of shadow . So how to calculate new shadow angle.

between 9:30 AM and 3:30 Pm my ω-modules angle has no affect on shadowing.

Comment: I would like to know more. (1) x and Lmin are fixed? (2) ω is changeable? (3) If you need the modules to be operational, they must directly face the sun? (That is, the sun rays are perpendicular to the modules?)

Comment: yes module length is fixed. yes W is changeable.

Comment: Try http://www.energyworksus.com/solar_power_incident_angle.html It does not explain the theory or the formula used behind it. However it comes with an angle calculator that might fit your requirement.

Comment: yes same thing i am looking for. But i need formula to calculate shadow length on basis i can calculate change in angle